# An Email About Company "Brand Registration Confirmation", SPAM?

Tags: spam, branding

One of my clients has the domain *EXAMPLE.com* for his company, today I received an email about someone trying to register *EXAMPLE* brand for

> From: *****  [mailto:***@***-***.org.cn] Sent: Friday, January
>   17, 2014 To: info
>
> Subject: URGENT "**Example**" Brand Registration
>   Confirmation
>
> Importance: High
>
> (It's very urgent, Please transfer this email to your CEO or
>   appropriate person, thanks)
>
> Dear Sir or Madam,
>
> We are a specialized company for domain name registration and
>   protection. Here, we have an issue about your intellectual property
>   rights to confirm with you.We formally received an application on
>   January  15,2013 that a company which self-styled "* * * Investments
>   Limited"were applying to register "**Example**" as their Brand name and
>   some domain names through our firm.
>
> Now we are handling this registration, and after our initial checking,
>   we found the name were similar to your company's, so we need to check
>   with you whether your company has authorized that company to register
>   these names. If you authorized this, we will finish the registration
>   at once. If you did not authorize, please let us know within 7
>   workdays, so that we will handle this issue better. Out of the time
>   limit we will unconditionally finish the registration for "* * *
>   Investments Limited".Looking forward to your prompt reply.

I am almost sure this is a scam, but thought of asking you if you have seen anything similar. Is their any chance that this is a legitimate message?

Comment: It's a scam. We see these all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely spam/scam... Here is an example that i have received recently.

> ```
> (Letter to the President or Brand Owner, thanks)
>
> Dear President,
> ```
>
> We are the department of Asian Domain Registration Service in China. I have something to confirm with you. We formally received an
>   application on Aguest 21, 2013 that a company which self-styled "FDH
>   Global Ltd" were applying to register "~REMOVED~" as their Brand Name
>   and some domain names through our firm.
>
> Now we are handling this registration, and after our initial checking, we found the name were similar to your company's, so we need
>   to check with you whether your company has authorized that company to
>   register these names. If you authorized this, we will finish the
>   registration at once. If you did not authorize, please let us know
>   within 7 workdays, so that we will handle this issue better. Out of
>   the time limit we will unconditionally finish the registration for
>   "FDH Global Ltd".Looking forward to your prompt reply.